# esp32, button onclick Can't find variable: of function

Tags: function, esp32, buttonclick

I cant get any of the buttons using onclick to recognise the functions. I get an error "cant find variable". Im very new to all this and at a loss. It doesn't matter which button I click I have the same issues with all of them.

in the below code,
I click on `<button onclick="show_admin()">Admin</button>` which should call `function show_admin()`.. What am I doing wrong please.

[Inspector output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWqXN.png)

```
const char main_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset='UTF-8'">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="500; url=/">

 
 
   <title>System Settings</title>
  <body onload="show_admin()">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>X Controller</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
```

These are my button

```
      <button onclick="show_admin()">Admin</button>
      <br/>
      <button onclick="show_wifi()">WIFI</button>
      <br/>
      <button onclick="show_tags()">Tags</button>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split right">
    <div class="centered" id="showdata">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
 </body>
  
<script>
```

These are my functions

```
function show_admin() {var table_data = <h1>Admin Settings</h1><br/>%s<br/>
  <form action="/ADMINSetting" method="POST">
<table><tr>
  <td> User Name </td> <td> <input type="String" name="UserName" placeholder="%s"></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td> Password </td> <td> <input type="String" name="UserPass" placeholder="%s">
</td></tr></table>
  <input type="submit" value="Update Admin Details">
</form>
  document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML = table_data
}

function show_wifi() { var table_data = <h1>WIFI Settings</h1><br/>%s<br/>
<form action="/WIFISetting" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td> SSID Network </td> <td> <input type="String" name="WifiSsid" placeholder="%s"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td> SSID Password </td> <td> <input type="String" name="SsidPass" placeholder="%s"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update Wifi Details">
</form>
document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML = table_data
}

function show_tags() { let table_data = <h1>Tag Settings</h1><br/>%s<br/>
<form action="/DEVICESetting" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td> Access Tag 1 </td> <td> <input type="String" name="TAG1" placeholder="%s"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Access Tag 2 </td> <td> <input type="String" name="TAG2" placeholder="%s"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Cleaner Tag 1 </td> <td> <input type="String" name="CTAG1" placeholder="%s"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update BLE Tag Details">
</form>
document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML = table_data
}
</script>
  
</body>
</html>

)=====";
```

I have tried rearranging the function and moving its position. with no luck

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have JSX installed, You can't just stick HTML elements into JavaScript like that. You will need to use quotes around all the HTML.
It looks like you're reusing the same tags anyway, why not stick all those tags into the HTML portion and update the values in Javascript? You can also update the CSS through JavaScript and set `display:none` if you want to hide an unused element.

Comment: Hi Roman, This is my hello world attempt at learning. so I dont really understand half of what you said.  Even if I move the tags into the html portion at this point I'm not sure how I would then update the java values. So you suggestion maybe something for me to look at, however right I am trying to understand why; even if I have an empty function, say x() and try to call it I still get the variable not found x() which is what i'm trying to understand as to why.  thanks and forgive my ignorance

Comment: The reason it says variable not found is because there are errors in your functions that I mentioned, so its not a valid function. Your functions would work if it wasn't for all the html in there. You're getting the "showdata" element by the id at the bottom of your functions. If you put all that html into the html portion and give them  a unique id as well, you can just update the value inside them the same way, with "innerHTML". You can choose to have a default value in them too if you want. Setting "innerHTML" on the element replaces everything inside the element with whatever you provide.

Comment: It can just be text without tags. `document.getElementById('your-id').innerHTML = "whatever you want"`

Comment: `document.getElementById('yourId').style.display = "none"` Thats an example of changing styles with `.style`. That line would make the element disappear. If you're going to be doing a lot of changes, then of course, set the element to a variable `myElement = document.getElementById('MyCoolElement')` then `myElement.innerHTML = "I'm so cool"`

Answer (score 0):

I added the below to the html section

```
<div class="split right">
 <div class="centered" id="showdata">
  <form id="adminForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td> User Name </td>
<td> 
<input type="String" name="UserName" placeholder="%s">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Password </td>
<td> 
<input type="String" name="UserPass" placeholder="%s">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update Admin Details">
</form>
```

and the following to the script section

```
 function admin(){ 
  
 document.getElementById("wifiForm").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("tagForm").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("adminForm").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: please also share where the admin() function will be called by the user